# N+だ+というN or NというN

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say “Noun + という + Noun”?

Or I have to say “Noun + だ + という+ Noun” ?

Or is it a same thing with difference in an informal/formal speech ?

Comment: Both forms are grammatically correct but used differently. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Are they exchangeable. I don’t know when to use だ after N and when not to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Both forms exist, but their meanings are quite different.

AというB means something like "the B that is called/referred to as A":

> ATCという会社　＝　the company called 'ATC'
>
> 青春というもの　＝　the thing referred to as 'youth'
>
> あなたという人　＝　the person that you are (fairly common expression in Japan)

AだというB is closer "the B that **it** is A", where A can be any sentence (including sentences ending in a noun):

> 悪いのはお前だという一言　＝　the comment that you are at fault
>
> ブラジルだというクイズの答え　＝　the quiz answer that it is Brazil
>
> 植物も生き物だという事実　＝　the fact that plants are living beings, too