# meaning of だというに

Tags: grammar

Could you explain how だというに works in the following case

> 先程までの緊張感もなく、相手は女神だというのに、俺は既にタメ口だった。
>
> Even though she was a goddess, I
> found myself speaking bluntly, without any of the anxiety I'd felt
> until a few minutes ago

I've checked the following answer
[N+だ+というN or NというN](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68963/n%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86n-or-n%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86n)
but it is a bit different.
Here there is no name directly after, it is followed directly by のに (Even though)

Could you explain me ?

Comment: You sure you've copied the sentence correctly? Is it not あいて**は**女神だと**いうのに** (not いう**に**のに)?

Comment: thanks I did indeed made a mistake

Comment: Decompose the clause as "((相手は 女神 だ) という) のに". It's the normal clause+という grammar plus のに to mean "despite".

Comment: thanks, I put your anlysis in my answer, in the case someone else has a similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use Garbaz's anlysis

((相手は 女神 だ) という) のに"

=  normal clause+  という grammar + のに ( "despite" )

So literally :

> **Despite the fact that (my companion/she) was a goddess**, I found myself speaking bluntly, without any of the anxiety I'd felt until a
> few minutes ago